# Problems with API Call and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem to insert a API call with request in mongodb with mongoose. Need your help!!! I have a problem with the api call and mongodb. I call the api call over an interval and delete all data with deleteMany and then I fill the data again with insertMany. That works well but the problem is that my _id is deleted every time and is reassigned when it is inserted. So I have problems with queries with the _id. Is there a more elegant way to update the data in mongodb every 10 minutes? How can i solve this problem any ideas. My target is to save the Api call from the url and then update it all 10 min. For all help i am very grateful.

```
const updateBaseCoin = async () => {
  request(
    {
      url:
        'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=eur&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=2h%2C1h%2C24h%2C7d%2C14d%2C30d%2C200d%2C1y%2C5y',
      json: true,
    },
    async (error, response, body) => {
      try {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          await BaseCoin.deleteMany({});
          await BaseCoin.insertMany(body.map((item) => item));
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  );
};

setInterval(updateBaseCoin, 10 * 10 * 1000);
```

Comment: If you want to preserve IDs then deleting everything and re-inserting new documents probably isn't the best approach--maybe consider updating instead? Or use a different field than `_id` for your lookups?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers. I think the best way for me is to take an other field then the id for my lookups. Have a good time and fun in programming!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, to solve the problem of the _id in a naive way is to change the map in that way (or something similar with another field as id) -

```
await BaseCoin.insertMany(body.map((item) => ({_id: item.id, ...item})));
```

Second,
This is not the best way to handle data fetching from another source.
You can create a mechanism that knows how to handle crud operations of data based on the existing data in the DB.

Comment: OK thanks for the answer. The way I can still imagine is to update all fields, but there has to be an easier way to give me less code. I am assuming that it is a common thing to do with Node and Mongodb to access data from an API and then update it.

Comment: Don't you care about deletions? If not, you can use the method updateMany with upsert true

Comment: Ok, can you make a example. I don't know upsert.